# Configuration of Turbo Gears with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, pydev, turbogears

I cannot find a way to get eclipse and TurboGears to work together.

I searched a lot online for an answer and cannot find it for the life of me.

I've successfully installed  `tg.devtools TurboGears2 WebOb Pylons WebFlash WebError Babel crank Routes WebHelpers Beaker decorator nose Mako WebTest Tempita Pygments repoze.lru MarkupSafe` via cmdline and other tutorials.

But, I cannot find a good tutorial or anything to configure in eclipse or aptana or similar IDE.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will need to install [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), a Python IDE for Eclipse, which comes as an Eclipse plugin.
You need to enter the URLs mentioned at http://pydev.org/download.html in Help -> Install new Software as a new Software Site and then select PyDev to be installed.

I suppose you installed these package inside a virtualenv, like most guides should suggest!
Then you will create an interpreter definition for PyDev, which will tell PyDev where to find the Python executable (`$VIRTUALENV/bin`) and which path to search for third-party packages (`$VIRTUALENV/lib/python2.x/site-packages`).

You do that in Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python. Click on the new button and select the python executable **from your virtualenv** (not the one from the system). In the next dialog, you need to select the package paths, I always need to add 
`/usr/lib/python...` to those.

Afterwards you can save the interpreter definition and create a new PyDev Project, select your interpreter and you're ready to go. If you would now quickstart a new TurboGears project in your project directory, you could happily code along in Eclipse.